The response of a linear quantum amplifier to broadband signals
I have been studying related knowledge of quantum linear amplifier noise limit recently, and the main reference material is Caves' literature. In this paper, the author uses equations (4.5, 4.40a, 4.40b) to describe how a phase-sensitive linear amplifier responds to broadband signals. I can accept this equation. However, the problem arises in the supplementary materials of another paper, where the author starts from equation
$$
   c(\omega)=\int_{\mathcal{I}}d\tilde{\omega}[M(\omega,\tilde{\omega})a(\tilde{\omega})+L(\omega,\tilde{\omega})a^{\dagger}(\tilde{\omega})]+f(\omega),
$$
where  $c(\omega)$ denotes the amplified output mode, $a(\tilde{\omega})$ denotes an input mode at frequency $\tilde{\omega}$ which is amplified with
gain $M(\omega,\tilde{\omega})$, $a^{\dagger}(\omega)$ is a phase-conjugated input mode which is amplified with signal gain $L(\omega,\tilde{\omega})$, and $f(\omega)$ represents the noise. This equation is similar to the process in Caves' article where equation (4.5) is used. However, in the supplementary materials' equation (15), the author uses the condition $|M(\omega)|^2=G_n(\omega)$ and $|L(\omega_i)|^2=G_n(\omega)-1$, which I don't understand how they come about. I would be very grateful if someone could provide relevant references.
